# Dynamic value updates from a bound service

Tags: java, android, dynamic, service, binding

I'm implementing a bound service that an activity can access via binding. I call methods of the service to get access to particular values. The service gets values updates every 30 millis with a Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate calls to the update method.

I'm expecting that with binding, updated values of the service will be pushed to activity and result in automatic updating of my activity values with only one call; but this is not the case.

Alternatively, I put the service method call in a runnable class and post it using a Handler object. However, even so, the values are not updated.

The connection onCreate():

```
mConnection = new ServiceConnection(){

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(context, "Service is connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            gyroService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "Service is disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
```

Here's the binding onStart of my activity method.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Bind to LocalService
    Intent gyroIntent = new Intent(this, GyroFusionService.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("activity", "calibration");
    gyroIntent.putExtras (bundle);
    bindService(gyroIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

Here's the runnable object I call using a handler:

```
private Runnable updateTiltTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (mBound) { 
            // Call a method from the LocalService.
            // However, if this call were something that might hang, then this request should
            // occur in a separate thread to avoid slowing down the activity performance.
            calibValues = ((GyroFusionService) gyroService).getCalibArray();
            baseValues = ((GyroFusionService) gyroService).getBaseArray();
            updateOrientationDisplay(); // on click, update the textView values
            //                  Toast.makeText(context, "received both arrays", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else 
            mPitchView.setText("Please wait. Service is not connected yet.");       
        }
};
```

I know the scheduled timer is working for sure, because on clicking a button in my activity class, I can get updated values from the service, but I do not know how to call or receive value updates from my service class on a regular basis.

My question can be summed up as:

Q1: What is existing mechanisms for getting value updates from bound services?
Q2: Is a push from service or a pull from activity more efficient for receiving value updates from a bound service? -in this case sensor updates?

Thanks for your time =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: For local bound service, activity can directly call methods on Service whenever activity wants to communicate. If the service needs to communicate back to activity it can use Handler with messenger.

Q2. In your case i think push strategy from service is more suitable.